# In R: How to compare a csv file and a list to keep common terms, and to list those separately

Tags: r, list, csv, intercept

I have a csv file with several columns of data, only one of which I wish to use directly. I have read the csv file into R like this:

```
list1<-readLines("myfile.csv")
```

Should I read it in like this though?:

```
list1<-read.csv(file="myfile.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE)
```

Let's say that this csv file, column 5, lists ("one", "three", "four")

I have a list in R like this:

```
list2<-c("one","two","three","three")
```

I want to compare the 5th column of the csv file to `list2` and have the common terms pulled and listed separately. I want to keep the repeats if a common term is listed more than once, for example "three" is listed twice in `list2`, so I want to list that twice in the new list as well.

I also want to not only list column 5 of the csv file but the entire row that contains the common term from column 5.

This is my best attempt but it does not acknowledge if a common term is found more than once in the csv file, nor does it list the entire row from which the common term is found in the csv file.

```
list1<-readLines("myfile.csv")

list2<-c("one","two","three","three")

intersect(list1,list2)
```

result: one, three

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

To figure out which elements of `list2` are in Column 5 of `list1`:

```
list2[list2 %in% list1[,5]]
```

And to get all the rows of `list1` where there are entries in column 5 that are also in `list2`:

```
list1[which(list1[,5] %in% list2),]
```

A little shorter:

```
list1[list1[,5] %in% list2,]
```

Consider this side note: it would be better practice not to call these two objects `list1` and `list2` since `list1` is a data.frame and `list2` is a vector and a `list` is another type of data structure in R (see `?list`).

Comment: No need for `which` there, I don't think.

Comment: Yeah, just added that.

Comment: supposed I have two csv dataframe I do like `list2[, list2[,2] %in% list[,2] ]` to check `which item of colum 2 of list is in list2`.